# Updating controller scope variable from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to make a directive that behaves like a container by transcluding its contents. My html looks like this

```
<test>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <button ng-click="alertName()">Alert</button>
</test>
```

Controller and directive are like this

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Eric Cartman';

    $scope.alertName = function() {
      alert($scope.name);
    };
  })
  .directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

      }
    };
  });
```

When the page loads I see 'Eric Cartman' in the textbox and when I click 'Alert' button I see 'Eric Cartman' in the dialog box. Till here everything is fine.

The problem is when I change the name in the textbox and hit the 'Alert' button it still alerts 'Eric Cartman'. Where am I going wrong?

[Here is the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nfFH6vHsCGto3LLE9Nw2?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the prototypical inheritance of the scopes and the bound variable being "top level" (i.e. `ng-model="name"`, instead of `ng-model="model.name"`).

Just wrap the value in an object:

```
// controller:
$scope.model = { name: 'Eric Cartman' };
// do not forget the alert!
```

Of course bind it properly:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.name" />
```

The prototypical inheritance is a topic that confuses people when first exposed to it; I haven't even tried to explain the concept here, there are plenty of sources in the web. You may study it or just take my word for it and **never use "top-level" 2-way bindings**!

Comment: Was just in the middle of answering this, here's the plunkr showing @Nikos explanation http://plnkr.co/edit/d0BQDUUJm6x1crXlAYB0?p=preview